# How to make the Last-child element with the after element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I need to make lines both side of the menu like below, 
[image]
I tried this with pseudo element

```
li:before {
content: "";
width: 2px;
height: 27px;
background-color: white;
float: left;
margin-top: 14px;
}
```

The line appeared on the left side of the menu but I need a line on the right side of the contact also. I tried the code below but did not work.

```
li:last-child:after {
content: "";
width: 2px;
height: 27px;
background-color: white;
float: right;
margin-top: 14px;
}
```

Comment: What did not work? What happened instead?

Comment: show html .. by the way not good idea to use float like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't use pseudo elements before and after like you did. I'd give the li items a border left (and the last one right as well). There's probably a cleaner way, but this is already a lot shorter than your method, and I guess it does the trick.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  padding-left:10px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}

li:last-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li>PROJECTS</li>
  <li>INFO</li>
  <li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
```